# Unable to connect to remote server using lftp

Tags: linux, ssl, lftp

I'm trying to establish a new ftps connection between two servers, say A and B.

Below are the commands I'm using for establishing the connection. I guess i'm able to connect to the remote server but unable to perform operations like `cd`,`ls` while in the remote server.

It just hangs while performing the `cd` operation(as shown below)

```
$ lftp
lftp :> set ftp:ssl-allow true
lftp :> set ftp:ssl-force true
lftp :> set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
lftp :> set ftp:ssl-protect-list true
lftp :> open -p 2121 sos13a-0501a.eu.hedani.net
lftp xxxx-xxxxx.xx.xxxxx.net:> cd /secure/gtd/VTXT
cd `/secure/gtd/VTXT' [Logging in...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to passive mode:

```
set ftp:fxp-passive-source true
```